# What is the difference between 'a minori ad majus' and 'a majori ad minus'

Tags: grammar-dikduk, language

Good afternoon,
I'm attempting to understand the "Thirty-Two Rules of Elezer B. Jose Ha-Gelili" and have come to the 5th rule and have a question;

***1. Summary of Problem***

- In reading the Thirty-Two Rules of Eliezer B. Jose Ha-Galili I came across the term "Argumentum a minori ad majus" and in my attempts to define the term properly I'm having issues understanding one aspect of it.

***2. Provide details and any research***

- I've utilized google and came across a few documents and sites which helped me to understand the term in question to the following extent;
- Qal wa-h omer (parallel concurrent deductions)
- this rule corresponds to the scholastic proof a fortiori ('a minori ad majus' or 'a majori ad minus')
- "a majori ad minus" = What applies in less important cases will apply in more important cases too
- But I'm not sure exactly what "a minori ad majus" references or implies (and I feel a bit 'slow' as I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face)

***3. When appropriate, describe what you've tried***

- Covered in point #2

Comment: Could it be that the terms got mixed up? a majori ad minus is referring to an instance where the logic is that if something works for the stronger/bigger, it surely works for weaker/smaller. Whereas a minori ad majus is an instance of something that is not allowed/forbidden in the weaker/smaller will surely be not allowed/forbidden in the stronger/bigger

Comment: That's very possible @Chatzkel thank you for the replay brother.

Comment: Thorough explanation here: https://content.iospress.com/articles/argument-and-computation/aac020

Comment: @Chatzkel Your explanation of the two modes looks correct per the above article; a minori ad maius is the negative form: "The house isn't big so the room can't be big."  Whereas a maiori ad minus is the positive form "The house is small so the room must be small."

Comment: Maybe because lo-taaseh are more numerous than asseh, therefore they chose to translate Kal w'Chomer (which includes both these a fortiori forms) as the negative form.

Comment: Can you post the link of the 32 rules?